# requests.get.json() error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am attempting to use requests' `json()`, but am getting the error: 
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I've looked at threads on this issue but their solutions haven't helped resolve the error.

- `r.ok()` returns true, and I'm definitely not getting an empty response
- `r.headers.get('Content-Type')` returns 
  `application/json;charset=utf-8` so it appears that it's in JSON format.

Relevant code bit:

```
r = requests.get("<url, it's very long>").json()
```

This is what's outputted when I print(r.text)

```
{"total":"1","data":[{"states":"ID,MT,WY","latLong":"lat:44.59824417, long:-110.5471695","description":"On March 1, 1872, Yellowstone became the first national park for all
 to enjoy the unique hydrothermal wonders. Today, millions of people come here each year to camp, hike, and enjoy the majesty of the park.","designation":"National Park","p
arkCode":"yell","id":"F58C6D24-8D10-4573-9826-65D42B8B83AD","directionsInfo":"Yellowstone National Park covers nearly 3,500 square miles in the northwest corner of Wyoming
(3% of the park is in Montana and 1% is in Idaho). Yellowstone has five entrance stations, and several are closed to regular vehicles during winter. It takes many hours to
drive between these entrances, so be sure to check the status of roads at the entrance you intend to use while planning your trip and before you arrive.","directionsUrl":"h
ttp:\/\/www.nps.gov\/yell\/planyourvisit\/directions.htm","fullName":"Yellowstone National Park","url":"https:\/\/www.nps.gov\/yell\/index.htm","weatherInfo":"Yellowstone's
 weather can vary quite a bit, even in a single day. In the summer, daytime highs can exceed 70F (25C), only to drop 20 or more degrees when a thunderstorm rolls through. I
t can snow during any month of the year, and winter lows frequently drop below zero, especially at night. Bring a range of clothing options, including a warm jacket and rai
n gear, even in the summer.","name":"Yellowstone"}],"limit":"50","start":"1"}
```

This is the content that's returned when I put the request through a REST client (Insomnia).

```
{
  "total": "1",
  "data": [
    {
      "states": "ID,MT,WY",
      "latLong": "lat:44.59824417, long:-110.5471695",
      "description": "On March 1, 1872, Yellowstone became the first national park for all to enjoy the unique hydrothermal wonders. Today, millions of people come here each year to camp, hike, and enjoy the majesty of the park.",
      "designation": "National Park",
      "parkCode": "yell",
      "id": "F58C6D24-8D10-4573-9826-65D42B8B83AD",
      "directionsInfo": "Yellowstone National Park covers nearly 3,500 square miles in the northwest corner of Wyoming (3% of the park is in Montana and 1% is in Idaho). Yellowstone has five entrance stations, and several are closed to regular vehicles during winter. It takes many hours to drive between these entrances, so be sure to check the status of roads at the entrance you intend to use while planning your trip and before you arrive.",
      "directionsUrl": "http:\/\/www.nps.gov\/yell\/planyourvisit\/directions.htm",
      "fullName": "Yellowstone National Park",
      "url": "https:\/\/www.nps.gov\/yell\/index.htm",
      "weatherInfo": "Yellowstone's weather can vary quite a bit, even in a single day. In the summer, daytime highs can exceed 70F (25C), only to drop 20 or more degrees when a thunderstorm rolls through. It can snow during any month of the year, and winter lows frequently drop below zero, especially at night. Bring a range of clothing options, including a warm jacket and rain gear, even in the summer.",
      "name": "Yellowstone"
    }
  ],
  "limit": "50",
  "start": "1"
}
```

Thus far `r.get().json()`, as well as json.loads(r.text) have come up with the same error.

Comment: Is that the entire response or the repeating unit?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't quite understand your question

Comment: That in itself is valid JSON (check on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)). Anecdotally, `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` always refers to getting some kind of JSONLines instead, from what I've observed

Comment: Interesting, I have not heard of JSONLines so I'll look into that. In the meantime, although when I make the request on a REST client I get valid JSON (check on jsonlint). But the r.text() is apparently NOT valid based on the response from jsonlint. I am not sure why this is.

Comment: The response you have posted is valid. That's why I'm asking if it's a "repeating unit" i.e. individually, lines are valid but separated by `\n`, and you've just posted the first example in what's returned

Comment: I think I see what you mean...I've posted the output from print(r.text) above

Comment: The exceotion does not indicate JSON Lines but an empty result or at least a result where the very first character is not valid. You should print the result body and maybe even its `repr()` for debugging.

Comment: @KlausD. is the r.text not the result body? Sorry, this is completely out of my area of knowledge. I did print that out hoping to see if there was something wrong with the first character but from r.text it seems fine. r.content, however, does strangely start like so: b'{"total":"1","d

Comment: The `repr` is the binary representation before decoding as the type bytes (marked with the `b`). It would allow you to see any unprintable characters that might have sneaked in. But your data look ok and should raise an error. Can manually decode it with `json.loads()`?

Comment: can the url be shared?

Comment: @KlausD. that worked, thank you. I can't believe I overlooked doing that.